# Xcode Error while programming in C

Tags: c, xcode, pthreads

I'm trying to create a program using Xcode. The program is very simple, it uses threads. 
I have done everything right. Or so I thought. This error comes up and I have do ideia what it means!

`Command /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1`

along with:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _thr_inc_low in (... a bunch of crap that is the directory of this file)  main.o
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

It means you have multiple `.o` files or libraries that include the symbol `_thr_inc_low`.

One of the common reasons for this is defining an object in a header file (rather than just declaring it, say with an `extern` or a prototype) that is included in multiple source files.

Can't tell more without seeing the relevant parts of your source code.